# NoSuchMethod Exception though method present in jar

Tags: java, jar, nosuchmethoderror, nosuchmethod

I am using one third party jar ( Jar has Model classes) in Restful web service. It is working fine in one environment. But it is not working properly in another environment. for Marshaling purpose I am using that jar. some of the fields are missed in marshaled XML. But those fields getter/Setter are available in jar. To verify that, I called that missed fields setter method, got NoSuchMethod Exception. I verified that jar is present in WAR. I kept the same jar in ext library option in server start up script. it works fine.

1. Why it is now working fine ?
2. What is the issue ?
3. Why NoSuchMethod Exception happened ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: double check if multiple version of same jar are present.

Comment: verified only one jar is in WAR